# How do you get the recipe for projectile ammunition?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I was playing multiplayer the other day, and a friend of mine was able to craft Projectile Ammunition using Ferrite.  I don't have that recipe, and he doesn't remember where he got it from, but he did confirm that there *is* a blueprint for it.

Googling didn't turn up any information at all about a recipe, I only found links that talked about the different weapon types.

Does anybody know where/how to get the recipe?

Comment: Did you unlock the weapon specialist, and if so, how far did you progress through his chain?

Comment: @Polygnome - I did, and I think I've done 2 of the missions for him.  Timmy Jim's answer got me the blueprint, I'm not sure if there's another way to do it, but it at least resolves my issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not think there is a blueprint for these.  I just checked in my game, and when I went into the crafting menu in my inventory, there was no option to make more ammo.  However, when I hovered over the ammo that I already had, and pressed <kbd>E</kbd> to craft more, it made more without any issues.  Interestingly enough, the ammo shows up in the crafting menu now.  This might be a bug.

One thing you can try then is have your friend transfer some ammo to you or find your own (I believe I first found my own ammo via searching containers that are randomly found on planets).  Once you obtain some, see if you can craft some via the method I just described above (hold <kbd>E</kbd> on it - or whatever the console equivalent would be).  If it does what it did for me, you should then be able to craft your own ammo in the crafting menu after that.

Comment: Aha!  I think you are right!  I just logged in and did what you said (Held "E" over the stack to make more) and it worked!
My friend didn't articulate to me that's how he did it, he just said that he made a bunch and gave me some when I had run out and said I didn't have the recipe.

Comment: He just confirmed that he made it from a blueprint, not from the 'Create more' option

Comment: @Taegost but what I am saying is, now that you crafted some via holding E, does it show that you have the blueprint when you open the crafting menu in your inventory?

Comment: Sentinels will also occasionally drop projectile ammunition when you kill them

Comment: @TimmyJim - Ok, well, you're right.  If you hold your cursor over it, and hold 'E', even if you don't have the Ferrite to make it, it gives you the blueprint (At least, it did for me).  So...  You found the answer after all!  Sorry, I had missed the "if it does what it did for me" part of your sentence when I read through it earlier

Comment: "I do not think there is a blueprint for these." This is **wrong**. There is; I have it. I can craft ammunition without having some. I do not recall where I got this, but the best bet would be the weapons master quest chain,  in your base.

Comment: @Polygnome I suppose yes there is a blueprint.  And my way does unlock the blueprint, but what I meant is there does not appear to be a way to get the blueprint via normal means.  I know that I did not do any weapons master quests, and what I said above is how I unlocked it.

Comment: I couldn't find any sources at least that stated a way to unlock it at least.

Comment: I didn't have the blueprint. I just manufacture more in the usual way. Once I'd made one batch, the recipe became available in my crafting menu.